# Redis .service file

Tags: ubuntu, redis

На Ubuntu 16.04 поставил Redis по [этой](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04) инструкции. Собирал через `make`, сконфигурил, всё работает, НО: при запуске/перезапуске через `sudo service redis restart` вывод строки "повисает" на некий таймаут, то есть, насколько я могу предположить, "изнутри" это работает так - после успешного запуска/перезапуска возвращается некий статус типа `true`, и в консоли появляется приглашение к вводу новой команды. У меня этот статус, условно говоря, не возвращается. Вывод команды `sudo service redis status`:

```
root@ubuntu-xenial:~# service redis status
● redis-server.service - Redis In-Memory Data Store
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) since Ср 2017-06-28 07:17:09 UTC; 14s ago
   Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
       man:redis-server(1)
   Process: 15864 ExecStopPost=/bin/run-parts --verbose /etc/redis/redis-server.post-down.d (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Process: 15882 ExecStartPost=/bin/run-parts --verbose /etc/redis/redis-server.post-up.d (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Process: 15878 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Process: 15874 ExecStartPre=/bin/run-parts --verbose /etc/redis/redis-server.pre-up.d (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Tasks: 3
    Memory: 10.2M
       CPU: 89ms
    CGroup: /system.slice/redis-server.service
            └─15881 /usr/local/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379       

июн 28 07:17:09 ubuntu-xenial systemd[1]: Starting Redis In-Memory Data Store...
июн 28 07:17:09 ubuntu-xenial run-parts[15874]: run-parts: executing /etc/redis/redis-server.pre-up.d/00_example
июн 28 07:17:09 ubuntu-xenial redis-server[15878]: 15878:C 28 Jun 07:17:09.164 # systemd supervision requested, but NOTIFY_SOCKET not found
июн 28 07:17:09 ubuntu-xenial run-parts[15882]: run-parts: executing /etc/redis/redis-server.post-up.d/00_example
июн 28 07:17:09 ubuntu-xenial systemd[1]: redis-server.service: PID file /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid not readable (yet?) after start-post: No such file or directory
```

Статус `activating` т.е. условно говоря вот тот статус, о котором я говорил, он видимо не возвращается-таки, а без него не ставится статус `active`.

Как починить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Нашёл](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/ubuntu/redis-server) PPA для Ubuntu, из которого можно поставить корректно работающую версию Redis. Вопрос закрыт.